# How to unit test a read-only SharedFlow properly?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, coroutine, mockk

I'm struggling with mine SharedFlow inside of the repo. So, in the real implementation I've got a singleton class that subscribes to different flows, makes some operations and then does `shareIn()` to all other places in the app as a single source of truth (service, VMs and so on). So it's a huge long chain of calls and setups.

When I'm trying to get a first emitted value, I'm either getting a non-completed coroutine issue (all other tests work fine with my test dispatcher, so I don't think that it's a dispatcher issue), or when I'm trying to use `sharedFlow.toList(someMutableList)` as I found in other examples, I'm getting an empty list of results. I cannot emit to the flow from my test because 1) I want to test that it works well by itself (that it combines other flows, makes some api calls etc) 2) and it's obviously a read-only class field and I want it to be so.

Here I created a really simple version of my repo and test class and a basic vision what I want to achieve.

```
import junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import org.junit.Test

class Repo(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {

    val flow1 = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val flow2 =  MutableStateFlow(1)

    val sharedFlow = flow1.flatMapLatest { zero ->
        flow2.map { one -> zero to one }
    }.transformLatest { (zero, one) ->
        emit(zero + one)
    }.shareIn(CoroutineScope(dispatcher), SharingStarted.Eagerly, 1)
}

class TestClass {

    @Test
    fun `checking the right state for the shared flow in repo`() = runTest {
        val repo = Repo(testDispatcher)

        launch {
            val state = repo.sharedFlow.firstOrNull()
            assertEquals(state, 1) // 0 + 1
        }.join()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've figured it out. The funniest and most awkward thing is that my example works perfectly, but the real implementation didn't.

The issue was with @RelaxedMockK that swallowed the exception that one of my flows was not mocked properly. Because of that the coroutine wasn't completed and caused a time out exception instead of a real-swallowed one (that's why I thought that maybe I had an issue with a dispatcher). So, if you use the test dispatcher, provide it to your repo, mock everything properly without relying on relaxed mockks when it's not a unit-result function and wait until the flow receives the first data, then everything should work well.